# $scope.$apply making dropdown act weird

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown;

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selected_category" data-ng-change="search(true, true)">
    <option value="0">Select Category</option>
    <option value="{{category.id}}" data-ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Which works perfect. However, I am manipulating the scope outside of Angular (valid reason) and I use this (It's in coffeescript but easy to understand)

```
scope.$apply (s) ->
  s.units = _me.attr('data-units')
  s.selected_category = parseInt(_me.attr('data-category'))

  s.search(true,true)
```

It *appears* to work in that everything depending on that `$scope.selected_category` variable changes (The correct products / text comes up) but the dropdown just goes blank if I've selected `Select Category` (IE: Not changed it since that change) and stays the same if anything else is selected. Looking at the blank dropdown when I use the element inspector in chrome I can see this:

```
<option value="? number:31 ?"></option>
```

What's up with that?

Comment: Do you have a valid need to use `ngRepeat` instead of the recommended `ngOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are missing the `ng-selected` attribute on `option` to let Angular know which option is currently selected:

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selected_category" data-ng-change="search(true, true)">
    <option value="0">Select Category</option>
    <option value="{{category.id}}" data-ng-selected="selected_category.id == category.id" data-ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>
```

However, it is prefered to use `ng-options` if you don't need to do anything to advanced.  So, I'd recommend (as @TheSharpieOne mentions in comments), that you change to this:

```
 <select ng-model="selected_category" ng-options="c.name for c in categories">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
 </select>
```

If you need to track by the `id` then use a `track by` clause:

```
 <select ng-model="selected_category" ng-options="c.name for c in categories track by c.id">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
 </select>
```